# Get the row count of a select... group by mysql statement

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, rowcount

I have a table of products which contains some 2000 clothing products, each product has a `grpIdent` field and a `productGroup` field.

when I run the following query:

```
select count(1) 
from tblclothingitems ci 
where productGroup='hel' 
group by productGroup, grpIdent
```

I get a resultset of 99 rows, according to SQL Yog, containing different values pertaining to the number of rows for each group.  BUT I want to return the number 99 giving the number of rows returned.

Does anybody have an idea on how I can achieve this please?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you'd like to get from the query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ([Your Query])
```

Will return the number of rows from your query returns.

Comment: This works a treat although I have just tried this query which does exactly the same:
SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT(grpIdent))
FROM tblclothingItems ci,(
 SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(grpIdent))
 FROM
  tblclothingitems cl
 WHERE
  productGroup='hel' AND liveToSite='y'
 GROUP BY
  productGroup, grpIdent
  ) p
WHERE
 productGroup='hel' AND liveToSite='y';

So thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
select **@@Rowcount** as myResultRowsCount
from tblclothingitems ci 
where productGroup='hel' 
group by productGroup, grpIdent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select productGroup, grpIdent, count(*) 
from tblclothingitems ci 
where productGroup='hel' 
group by productGroup, grpIdent;
```

will return counts for different values of grpIdent.

Point 1.  You could nest the table and select count(*) to count the rows.

Point 2.  This below is the preferred query for the cardinality of the values.

```
select count (distinct grpIdent) 
from tblclothingitems ci 
where productGroup='hel';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single value, you have to select into a variable.
Like this:

```
DECLARE @Count INT;
select @Count = count(1) from tblclothingitems ci where productGroup='hel' group by productGroup, grpIdent
RETURN @Count
```

**EDIT:**
Seems i got your question wrong. If i understand it right now, you could use:
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productgroup) FROM tblclothingitems

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in function of MySQL "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" which works as follows, using your example query above;

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS count(1) 
from tblclothingitems ci 
where productGroup='hel' 
group by productGroup, grpIdent
```

Then issue a second MySQL command;

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

And use that result within your software - you can use this in many areas, for example updating data, or where you are using a "LIMIT" clause to restrict the number of rows returned to your app.

The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tells MySQL to calculate the number of rows *ignoring* the "LIMIT" clause, which allows you to do something like.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM `myTable` 
WHERE `title` LIKE "%blah%" 
LIMIT 100,10;
```

To extract 10 rows starting from the 100th row, and then;

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Which will tell you how many rows there are with "blah" in the `title` field in the whole table, you can then present this info as "Showing 10 rows from 12345 total"

Comment: I have tried using the inbuilt functions but as I am using the sql in an async AJAX application I want to only hit the database once, and return the rowcount with the results.

I have managed to find out this solution:

SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT(grpIdent))
FROM tblclothingItems ci,(
 SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(grpIdent))
 FROM
  tblclothingitems cl
 WHERE
  productGroup='hel' AND liveToSite='y'
 GROUP BY
  productGroup, grpIdent
  ) p
WHERE
 productGroup='hel' AND liveToSite='y';

which uses a derived query to give me the results I am expecting.

Comment: Sounds good, but it doesn't give you the "data" as well doing it that way. 

My suggestion above allows you to pull the data from the database, so that you can perform other tasks with it like building some output, and then also getting the number of rows with the second SELECT statement.

The second SELECT doesn't actually 'hit' the database, MySQL returns this directly from its internals - you don't even have to supply the database to run it against, just ensure that the connection to the server stays open until after the second SELECT...  :)